# Delphi XE5 android app keydown and keyup events

Tags: android, delphi, events, keydown

I want the keydown (or up) event for an edit-box so I can do a database lookup for the text entered so far. This works fine in Windows, but on Android only the Enter is send.
Does anyone know how to capture the key-events in XE5 of the virtual keyboard?

Comment: OnChangeTracking is doing the job for me in this case. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that detecting keyboard events was ever the right way to solve this problem. That's because there are many ways of getting text into a control, and not all of them involved pressing keys. You are really trying to detect when the text of the edit control changes. For that you simply listen to the [`OnChangeTracking`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Edit.TCustomEdit.OnChangeTracking) event.

Comment: This is the same for iOS, since iOS doesn't have OnKeyPress/OnKeyDown, etc. events.

Comment: I disagree that you can simply assume that the OP is trying to do something they shouldn't.  It is more than reasonable to respond only to user originated input (key events) to avoid triggering processing when you programmatically set some edit control (or other UI element) value to match some pre-set result, for example.  It would be more helpful to explain what the FireMonkey equivalent of onEditorActionListener (the native Android mechanism for such things) is, if such an equivalent even exists.  ;)

Comment: @Deltics There won't be such a direct equivalent. And I was not thinking of programmatic change. I was thinking of input from clipboard or gesture or swype